# Sub menu overlapping

Tags: javascript, css

I am hoping an CSS pro might be able to help me.

I am working on a toggle menu (mobile view) and I am running into problems with the submenu. Any li that sits below a li with children, is not visible. If I remove the li with children, everything displays fine.

Can anyone suggest a CSS fix?

The website to look at is [here](http://expresswordpress.co.uk/EmptyWordpress/), the toggle menu I am referring to is for mobile view. Any li below "pages" cannot be seen.

Thanks in advance to anyone who may be able to help me figure this out.

Answers:-

I basically want all menu items to stack, regardless of whether there are children or not. Just as they are at the moment, but with all menu items visable.

Comment: You have by default set display to "block" at the submenu element level in case if you have not set it, you could have made some mistake in jquery implementation of the menu, its not purely a CSS issue, tag this question to jquery and you may get better responses

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand what you want but try `remove position:absolute` on `media="screen"
nav#nav-mobile ul` You can make a screenshot and explain a bit what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not positioning the sub-menu absolutely does what you want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxoxr.png

[image]

Comment: No I didn't intend to leave it like that. I have now formatted it a bit more :-)